# Using the Google+ API (PHP,) how can I make a public activity feed always display a specific user's data, but not the current logged in user?

Tags: php, google-plus

I set up the Google+ API php client on my server and I am able to pull my own feed activity but only because I authorized it. What I am looking to do is just display a feed of always my content on my personal web page, a la a widget.

Is this difficult? It seems like it should be straight forward. I have limited PHP knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I do.

```
$client = new apiClient();
$client->setDeveloperKey($api_key);
$plus = new apiPlusService($client);
$person = $plus->people->get($plus_id);
$collection = 'public';
$activities = $plus->activities->listActivities($plus_id, $collection);
```

There is an example in the SDK that shows this.

Comment: Answers on Stack Overflow are really bad for people with limited coding knowledge, but thanks for your attempt at helping.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're storing the access token that grants access to your user data and then making all of your API calls with that access token.

When your application is running in production, with multiple users accessing it, you should authenticate and store the access token for each user. You should then use the user's specific access token for all requests on their behalf.

It's important that you never cross the streams. Treat an access token as you would treat confidential user information. Do not expose one user's token or the result of API calls using that token to other users.